# How to configure metaspace with SBT

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to configure metaspace for SBT

```
export SBT_OPTS="-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512M -XX:MetaspaceSize=256M -Xms2G -Xmx2G"
```

but when I run `sbt -v`, I have the following output :

```
[process_args] java_version = '1.8.0_11'
# Executing command line:
java
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512M
-XX:MetaspaceSize=256M
-Xms2G
-Xmx2G
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
-jar
/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.7/libexec/sbt-launch.jar
```

The problem seems that my custom value for `MaxMetaspaceSize` is overrided with another value, as shown in output above.

---

SBT version : 0.13.7

Java version : 1.8

OS : OSX

Answer (score 45, accepted):

(copy-pasted from a dear coworker who found the solution)

```
sbt -mem 2048
```

=>

```
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
```

the default metaspace is based on the xmx value specified with the "-mem" option ;-)

Answer (score 15):

When using sbt 0.13.6 or higher you can create a .sbtopts file in your project root with:

```
-J-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512M
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that memory options are only correctly handled when they are specified in `JAVA_OPTS`

setting `export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512M -XX:MetaspaceSize=256M -Xms2G -Xmx2G"`

gives

```
sbt -v
[process_args] java_version = '1.8.0_40'
# Executing command line:
java
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512M
-XX:MetaspaceSize=256M
-Xms2G
-Xmx2G
-jar
/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.8/libexec/sbt-launch.jar

[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/ant/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to ant (in build file:/Users/ant/)
>
```

Not sure if it's a bug or a feature

Answer (score 4):

```
export SBT_OPTS="-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
```

works for me in sbt 0.13.11:

```
sbt -v
[process_args] java_version = '1.8.0_91'
# Executing command line:
java
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-jar
```